# how to check or select the radio button based from the data from the db table?

Tags: php, mysql

am having problem, my app doesn't seem to check the radio button based from the saved data. actually i have two radio buttons, it has a value of 1 or 2 , the saving of the value does work, but when the user visited the app again using his/her account,none of the radio buttons are checked

here's the code for the pulling of data of the radio button from the db table

```
//User.php
public function getGalleryMenuStyle($id = ''){
    $gallerymenustyle = "SELECT gallery_menu_style FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$id;
    $this->dbSelectQuery = $gallerymenustyle;
    $checkedgallerymenustyle = $this->userDBSelect();
       if($checkedgallerymenustyle){
           return $checkedgallerymenustyle;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
}
```

here's the code for the front-end

```
$userCats = new User();
$user_id = $_SESSION['userData']['user_id'];
$checkedgallerymenustyle = $userCats->getGalleryMenuStyle($user_id);

    <div align="center" class="radio_group">
        <input type="radio" id="gallerymenustyle1" class="element radio" name="gallerymenustyle[]" value="1" <?php if($checkedgallerymenustyle == 1){ echo "selected"; }?> /> Gallery Link - In the navigation of my website, display one "gallery" link<br />
        <input type="radio" id="gallerymenustyle2" class="element radio" name="gallerymenustyle[]" value="2" <?php if($checkedgallerymenustyle == 2){ echo "selected"; }?> /> Category Links - In the navigation of my website, display a separate link to each category.
    </div>
```

how to fix this ? is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Did you try echoing out `$checkedgallerymenustyle` on the front-end to see if you are getting the proper value?

Comment: ok, so instead of using echo, try `print_r($checkedgallerymenustyle);` this will show you what's in your array, and you can see if they value you need is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons use "checked" not "selected"

Comment: Try removing the "if(...)" then on the first one.  If it shows up checked, then your value is not in the expected range [1,2] but if it is not, your check-enabling script is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 <div align="center" class="radio_group">
        <input type="radio" id="gallerymenustyle1" class="element radio" name="gallerymenustyle[]" value="1" <?php if($checkedgallerymenustyle == 1){ echo "checked=\"yes\""; }?> /> Gallery Link - In the navigation of my website, display one "gallery" link<br />
        <input type="radio" id="gallerymenustyle2" class="element radio" name="gallerymenustyle[]" value="2" <?php if($checkedgallerymenustyle == 2){ echo "checked=\"yes\""; }?> /> Category Links - In the navigation of my website, display a separate link to each category.
    </div>
```

checked="yes"

Comment: it must and I think that you are returning true not 1 check that.